# How can I reorder vertical columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wan to know if it's possible to re-order vertical columns on Bootstrap 3.

```css
.col-xs-8 {
    background: magenta;
}
.col-xs-4 {
    background: cyan;
}
.col-xs-12 {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">A</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">B</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">C</div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">D</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QtPd2/1/)

What I want it's to move the items on the sidebar from ABCD to BCAD

Comment: why don't you just change the order in the markup? you're using `xs` for the columns size so the layout will be the same no matter the screen size

Comment: I used the xs class because the Fiddle space for the demo is too small to see the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have to insert first child just before the last child.

You can do it with jquery. **[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/QtPd2/4/)**

```
$( ".flexbox div:first" ).append().insertBefore( ".flexbox div:last" );
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve can not be done for responsive layout.....but assuming you have static content then, it can be done using `margin`s :

Here is a  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QtPd2/9/)

Wrap your ordering divs in some parent div and apply responsive layout to it....in the demo, i have dome that through `abcd` class ( *its not responsive though since its in pixels*)

**HTML**

```
<div class="abcd">
   <div class="col-xs-12 " style="margin-top:-110px;color:#000">A</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-150px;color:#000">B</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-130px;color:#000">C</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-90px;color:#000">D</div>
 <div>
```

**EDIT :**

[**demo with percentage value**](http://jsfiddle.net/QtPd2/12/)

In `%ge`, you can vreate something like :

```
 <div class="abcd">
   <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-13%;color:#000;">A</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-33%;color:#000">B</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-23%;color:#000">C</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-3%;color:#000">D</div>
 <div>
```

**CSS**

```
.abcd {
    margin-top:33%;/* keep this equal to margin of B, but with opposite sign */
}
```