# Twitter Bootstrap: column re-ordering for full width divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

It looks like a simple task, but can't get it working. I need to re-order divs for tablets, which are 100% width. Please take a look at the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/711p2dLb/) to see what I mean.

Original reference:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: google search : "bootstrap reorder vertically" or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780146/bootstrap-push-pull-vertically

Comment: you want divs to be 100% width for all screen sizes?

Comment: I would like to avoid using javascript. @Danko don't understand your fiddle? Is it related? @tmg no, just for `-sm`

Comment: so col-sm-12 and col-md-6?

Comment: @tmg exactly like that

Comment: Jajaj lol sorry wrong link is this http://jsfiddle.net/711p2dLb/2/

Comment: @Danko, yep, that's how I want, but tmg already provided the correct answer so I have to accept his/her :)

Comment: yep ok :D my miss for bad copy/paste the link I will upvote that answer too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its doable if you think mobile first. Place the divs in the order you want them to appear in small viewports and then reorder them for larger viewports.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        <div style="background:red">
            Put the one that for small screen on top
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        <div style="background:green">
            Put the one that for small screen on bottom
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You and me came up with identical code. Here, [take this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aj2wcvw/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack around that if you don't want to do it mobile first:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
      .row.reorder-xs {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        direction: rtl; /* Fix the horizontal alignment */
      }

      .row.reorder-xs > [class*="col-"] {
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
        direction: ltr; /* Fix the horizontal alignment */
      }
    }
```