# Bootstrap 3 column ordering on collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have these two columns inside a row:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                         <p>Column A</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                        <p>Column B</p>
                        <div style="padding:10px;" class="text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark pulse2"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So that whe the screen size turns to xs they collapse in this order:

Column A

Column B

But how can I make them collapse the other way 'round?
From other questions I red I tried to add the class `col-sm-pull-8` to the A column and `col-sm-push-4` to the B Column.

But it doesn't work, it just mess up the layout and they still collapse like:

Column A

Column B

Comment: Will this answer require a css only solution?

Comment: I would prefer so. I could fix this with jQuery in a blink of an eye, but I'd prefer a specific solution. there must be a way!

Comment: Bootstrap is mobile first front-end framework. You need to think mobile first. Check this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466407/twitter-bootstrap-column-ordering-for-full-width-divs/26466793#26466793

Answer (score 1, accepted):

col-sm-pull-8 and col-sm-push-4 work fine, you just need to swap your order:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-8">
        <p>Column B</p>
        <div style="padding:10px;" class="text-center">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark pulse2"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
        <p>Column A</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yutngfjw/

Comment: There are some issues in your answer, but it gave me the imput and I fixed my problem, thanks.

Comment: Ah yeah, I see them but I think you get the main aspect ;)