# Reordering with bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can someone help me with the html to reorder columns below using bootstrap 3:

```
 ----- ----- -----
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
 ----- ----- -----
```

To this:

```
 -----
|  2  |
 -----
|  1  |
 -----
|  3  |
 -----
```

I know this has something  to do with push/pull I just cant to seem to get it right.

**Edit**

And som code that i can't get to work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-md-push-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-2">3</div>
</div>
```

On mobile it looks good but not on desktop.

**Solution**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-md-push-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-8">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to do it , can you post some code

Comment: think mobile first and place div-2 first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466407/twitter-bootstrap-column-ordering-for-full-width-divs/26466793#26466793

Comment: I usually end up breaking them into duplicate divs, so the "1" up above would have the class hidden-xs and a duplicate for down below has the class visible-xs. Make sense?

Comment: I faced the same problem time ago. Try this, sure it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171408/how-do-i-change-bootstrap-3-column-order-on-mobile-layout

Comment: You want just with Bootstrap or CSS solution would do?

Comment: Check this out - https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward, they key point is that we cannot reorder the columns in mobile mode. We should think of it as mobile first, then reorder the columns on larger screens using `.col-*-push-#`, `.col-*-pull-#` helper classes:

```css
.red {
    background: red;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="red col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">2</div>
        <div class="green col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">1</div>
        <div class="blue col-sm-4">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom class for each and use the flex box CSS concept.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 one">First box</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 two">Second Box</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 three">Third Box</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.one {
  order: 2;
}

.two {
  order: 1;
}

.three {
  order: 3;
}
```

[**Codeply**](http://www.codeply.com/go/4VVRlT11JH)

Comment: For my project I need to use bootstrap push/pull, but your example code works fine to, thanks ;o)