# Bootstrap - How to show columns inverse in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-4"></div>
    <div class = "col-md-8"></div>  
</div>
```

I have two columns in one row. I want to show *col-md-8* firstly in mobile. Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466407/twitter-bootstrap-column-re-ordering-for-full-width-divs/26466793#26466793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use column order manipulation techniques with the help of col-lg-push and col-lg-pull classes. 
Pull "pulls" the div towards the left of the browser and and Push "pushes" the div away from left of browser.

[image]

In case if you want to use this in only in mobile then you can add those classes with the help of jQuery. You can read about that here: [Column order manipulation using col-lg-push and col-lg-pull in Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057270/column-order-manipulation-using-col-lg-push-and-col-lg-pull-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

Create the mobile layout first (place the 8 wide col first), then use push and pull to adjust for desktop..

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-push-4 col-md-8"> </div> 
     <div class="col-md-pull-8 col-md-4"> </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/AGFrU2kffU)