# Bootstrap: change order of fullwidth columns on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such schema:

```
[col-1][col-2]
```

(all of them have width of 12-block)

and my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">2</div>
```

is it possible to show in such way on xs-mobile devices?:

```
2
1
```

i tried so:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-xs-push-12">1</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 col-xs-pull-12">2</div>
```

but it doesn't help (

Comment: place them like you want in mobile and after apply pull-push [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466407/twitter-bootstrap-column-re-ordering-for-full-width-divs/26466793#26466793)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the columns in their mobile first order, and then use push/pull to re-order them on larger screens...

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-push-7">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 col-md-pull-5">1</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/PetKacoXyT

Answer (score 0):

For mobile device you can change the order like this..

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7">2</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5">1</div>
```