# HTML Changing around columns depending on browser size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how I can swap around content depending on the browser size (mobile scaled). I am using Bootstrap here.

See below code snippet. You can see I have 2 rows with each a picture and text on either side. First one is Pic on the left and text on the right and the second one is the opposite.

So the setup is

```
<IMG> <Text>
<Text> <IMG>
```

When you reduce the browser size (aka mobile version) it automatically jumps to:

```
<IMG>
<TEXT>
<TEXT>
<IMG>
```

Works all very well.

But how can I make it instead:

```
<IMG>
<TEXT>
<IMG>
<TEXT>
```

I understand that I could use the CSS @media query depending on browser size to basically duplicate the content and do a "display:hidden" on it etc.

But is there any other solution to fix this easier instead of duplicating everything? I've found similar questions but nothing specific like this other than using the @media "cheat".

Opinions & help is much appreciated. 
Many thanks

---

PS: Just to be clear. I want the order to be

```
<IMG> <Text>
<Text> <IMG>
```

when it is "Desktop" (currently correct) but need it be

```
<IMG>
<TEXT>
<IMG>
<TEXT>
```

when it is "Mobile" (re-ordered). So it has to change its order dynamically when the browser resizes. As far as I know a "Push" "Pull" with Bootstrap won't do that and is obviously static even with a @media query. Correct?

```
           <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 half-left" >
                            <img class="" src="..."/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 half-right">
                            <p>Content here</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">                       
                        <div class="col-sm-6 half-left" >
                            <p class="largeFontP">Content here</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 half-right">
                            <img class="" src=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean "a Push Pull with Bootstrap won't do that and is obviously static even with a @media query", but the push pull will work as explained in several answers below.

Comment: *As far as I know a "Push" "Pull" with Bootstrap won't do that and is obviously static even with a @media query. Correct?* No. The answer by ZimSystem even has a code pen demonstrate that the push/pull are set to happen at specific break points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: change order of fullwidth columns on mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329495/bootstrap-change-order-of-fullwidth-columns-on-mobile-devices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bootstrap you can 'push' and 'pull' columns to the left and right with push and pull classes like so.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 half-left col-sm-push-6">
     <img class="" src="..."/>
</div>
```

This way on smaller browsers the columns could be pushed right or pulled left accordingly. The above code would push this `<div>` 6 columns to the right of it's initial position. To move it 6 columns to the left on small screens you would use the similar class `col-sm-pull-6`.

Read more in the bootstrap documentation here under 'column ordering':

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I never knew that "push" "pull" would work in that context. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make the markup work for the mobile layout first (think "mobile-first"), then use `push` `pull` class to adjust for larger screens..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 half-left">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/500x200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 half-right">
            <p>Content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 half-right col-sm-push-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/500x200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 half-left col-sm-pull-6">
            <p class="largeFontP">Content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/NSOeIemufV

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries and i also recommend using flexbox.

Links here: [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

your issue is using divs for rows. yu should instead use one parent or something like this

```
<parent>
   <wrap><img><text></wrap>
   <wrap><img><text></wrap>
   <wrap><img><text></wrap>
   <wrap><img><text></wrap>
</parent>
```

and then just give the parent display:flex and flex-wrap: wrap. well just go play around with flexbox.