# Why is my Bootstrap push & pull divs not working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have 2 divs `besides` each other for `col-md and higher`, while having them `above` each other for `col-sm and lower`. So I tried to use the push and pull feature as mentioned in the docs but somehow it's not working. What I'm trying to do is get the RIGHT div `above` the LEFT div on col-sm and lower, basically reversing the order.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-push-12 col-md-7">LEFT</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-12 col-md-5">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ko7euh77/1/

Comment: `.col-sm-push-12` and `.col-sm-pull-12` will not work. Place your divs as you want them to appear in smaller screens and then pull & push them. You can find a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466407/twitter-bootstrap-column-re-ordering-for-full-width-divs/26466793#26466793)

Answer (score 55):

You just need to think "[mobile-first](http://blog.codeply.com/2015/04/06/responsive-bootstrap-layouts/)"..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-push-7 col-md-5">RIGHT</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-pull-5 col-md-7">LEFT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/2SN4r7KGwV

---

**Bootstrap 4 Update**

The push pull class are now `order-*` (using flexbox) in Bootstrap 4.

https://www.codeply.com/go/l3BOOH6JM9

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 order-md-2">
        <div class="card card-body">RIGHT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 order-md-1">
        <div class="card card-body">LEFT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you :)

Comment: @ZimSystem can you please explain the code please so that others can know what they are doing wrong.

Comment: i have followed your approach but still my buttons inside the code is not working .

Comment: You need to create the mobile layout first, then adjust it as needed for larger screens. It's explained more here: http://blog.codeply.com/2015/04/06/responsive-bootstrap-layouts/

Comment: Bootstrap changed this between `v4 alpha 6` and `latest 4.x` thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the version you are using, for bootstrap 4 and above you can push and pull like this: 
one more thing here order doesn't mean to the grid of the scree it will be the no.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 order-md-2 order-sm-1"  >
       <div >RIGHT</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-10 order-md-1 order-sm-2 ">
      <div >LEFT</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[Here are the bootstrap docs for further reading](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order)