# Bootstrap Altering a child div in a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 div1">DIV1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 div2">DIV2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 div3">DIV3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 div4">DIV4</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.row div{
  height: 100px;
}
.div1{
  background: blue;
}
.div2{
  background: red;
}
.div3{
  background: darkcyan;
}
.div4{
  background: cyan;
}
```

Its ok in normal view
[image: Normal view] 
Is it possible to alter div4 with div3 on mobile view like below image
[image]

Comment: use width:100% !important css property in your div.

Comment: see cyan color is on third position on mobile view

Comment: @nikolas Think mobile first place the "div4-cyan" div first and then "div3-darkcyan", then use pull & push classes. You can view [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466407/twitter-bootstrap-column-re-ordering-for-full-width-divs/26466793#26466793) and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aj2wcvw/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the color of `div3` and `div4` using media query for mobile `min-width: 767px`

```css
.row div{
  height: 100px;
}
.div1{
  background: blue;
}
.div2{
  background: red;
}
.div3{
  background: darkcyan;
}
.div4{
  background: cyan;
}

@media(max-width:767px){
  .div3{
    background: cyan;
  }
  .div4{
    background: darkcyan;
  }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 div1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 div2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 div3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 div4"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Any other tricks? Really I want to alter whole div content.