# realign columns in mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap frame work and Wordpress. My site brings in two different kinds of posts

html - post type 1 - image on the right

```
<section class="row row-eq-height">  
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="section-content">
     ... content ...
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6 section-img">
  ... image that takes up full column space ...
 </div>
</section>
```

html - post type 2 - image on the left

```
<section class="row row-eq-height"> 

  <div class="col-md-6 section-img">
   ... image that takes up full column space ...
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="section-content">
     ... content ...
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

css

```
.row-eq-height {
position: relative;
display: flex; 
min-height: 400px;
}

.row-eq-height .col-md-6, 
.row-eq-height .col-md-12 {
flex: 1;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.section-content {
position: relative;
flex: 1;
text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.section-content { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: 0; left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px; 
}

.section-img { min-height: 400px; }

.row-eq-height { display: block; }

.row-eq-height .col-md-6, 
.row-eq-height .col-md-12 {
  flex: 1;
  display: block;
}
}
```

The goal is the columns in each post overlap (content column over-top image column) when the screen is 768px. The post type 1 (image on the right) works fine. The post type 2 (image on the left) the text content goes underneath the image column.

I tried using push and pull classes with no success

Comment: Do you want to keep those at the same row/line instead of going underneath?

Comment: Think mobile first. Place "content" column before "image" column for post-type-2 as well, you can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466407/twitter-bootstrap-column-re-ordering-for-full-width-divs/26466793#26466793).

Comment: right right, I didn't think of that. so simple thanks